# Prevent perceived infinite loop with jQuery bind on textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that receives quite a bit of usage (600+ users a day), so the issue I describe below is not common.  Truth be told, it's been reported to me on a few occasions, but I have yet to reproduce the issue myself.  I've used browserstack.com to test in all various browser\OS combinations, but this code has just worked every time...

So here's the scenario.  My website involves vehicle warranties, and the whole process begins with the user entering a Vehicle Identification Number (VIN).  VIN's are an unholy mix of numbers and letters, but there are always 17 of them.  When the user enter's a VIN, I perform some logic that validates the VIN, returns the details of the vehicle, and allow them to validate that they're working with the intended vehicle.

For the past 6 months, the code below has worked (and continues to do so).  When the user enters 17 characters, I call a method called "lookupVIN", passing the pertinent information, and returning the validation information to the user.

The issue is, I've had a few reports that when the user enters the screen (txtVIN is the only textbox on the screen when the page initially loads), the browser immediately locks up.  I've asked what browsers, and I've been told IE11\Win 8 and Chrome\Win 7.  My thinking is that this code below is entering a loop - even though the user has yet to enter a single character in the txtVIN textbox.

Are there any reasons this code should be altered based on the scenario described above? Are there any "safety checks" I could be performing to ensure a loop isn't enetered?  Any thoughts are welcome, thanks!

```
//Note, all code below is using jQuery 1.10.2
var VinLength = 17;

$('#txtVIN').bind('input propertychange', function (e) {
    if (!e) { e = window.event; }
    //Ignore konami code...
    if ((e.keyCode == undefined) || (e.keyCode != 37 && e.keyCode != 38 && e.keyCode != 39 && e.keyCode != 40 && e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46)) {
        scrubVIN('#txtVIN'); //performs trim and such..

        if ($(this).val().length == VinLength) {
            lookupVIN($('#txtVIN').val(), $('#hidDIN').val()); //Performs VIN lookup
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Any online link this can be tested? I'm on chrome/win7

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff but sorry, this is inside a "private" web portal..

Comment: Is that the only code on the page? We need a complete code example in order to begin venturing guesses. Also, what debugging have you done with the developer tools?

Comment: A couple of ideas offhand.  First, as of jQuery 1.7, you should use `.on()` instead of `.bind()` (http://api.jquery.com/bind/)  Second, I've heard of a few problems when using `input propertychange`.  Maybe try assigning it to a keyup, change, or blur event.

Comment: @j08691 there is other code involved, but it's either scrubbing logic (trim, to upper, stuff like that) or a call to our validation service.  I *could* add it, but I honestly don't think it's related at this time - partially because I don't want to junk up this question.  Otherwise.. no, I havent debugged anything at all because I havent been able to reproduce the issue..

Comment: @HowardRenollet thanks so much for the advice, that's exactly what i was looking for, if I was mis-using something.  I'll take a look into this further..